# The solution of Abel's equation of the first kind

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solving a problem I was faced with an Abel's equation of the first kind as

$$y'-(ak\cos kx)y^3+(1-W)ak\cos kx=0,$$ where $a,b$ and $k$ are nonzero constant and $W=b+a\sin kx$. I also know that $y(0)=1-b$.

I searched the Web and read some papers, however there are some solutions for some particular cases which do not contain my case.

Any ideas about finding either an analytical solution or numerical?

Comment: sorry I forgot to write =0  :)

Answer (score 2):

$$y'-(ak\cos kx)y^3+(1-W)ak\cos kx=0,$$
$$y'-ak\cos(kx)y^3+(1-b-a\sin(kx))ak\cos(kx)=0$$
Change of variable: $\quad t=a\sin(kx)+b-1,$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=ak\cos(kx)\frac{dy}{dt}$

$ak\cos(kx)\frac{dy}{dt}-ak\cos(kx)y^3+(1-b-a\sin(kx))ak\cos(kx)=0$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}-y^3-t=0$$

Of course, this is still an Abel's ODE, but much simpler than the original one : There is no parameter in it.

Apparently, this is not a solvable case in terms of standard special functions. So, it is suggested to continue thanks to numerical method.

Comment: JJacquelin this is the canonical form of Abel. Right? 
There are some papers that gave some solutions for some cases of Abel. I am wondering if there is not anything related to this one. As you mentioned it is much simpler now

Comment: @Majid.I suggest this paper : https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf . Sorry, I have not enough available time just now. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your time!
In this paper a solution is suggested for a restricted first kind of Abel. Moreover I do not know how to write this equation as the Eq. (3) suggested in this paper. Any suggestion?

Comment: Apparently, this is not a solvable case in terms of standard special functions. So, it is suggested to continue thanks to numerical method.